# What is the difference between using assign and always block for combinational circuit in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

For example, I want to write a +4 unit for the Program Counter. I have to assign the output to be input+4, which mode of assigning value I'd better use?

```
module multiplexer_add4(in, out);
  input in;
  output out;
  
  assign out=in+4;
endmodule
```

or

```
module multiplexer_add4(in, out);
  input in;
  output reg out;
  
  always@(*)
    out<=in+4;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `assign` statements are used to connect different devices via `nets`. Always blocks are used to express behavior of those devices.

In general the 'assign' statements are used to assign values to nets. always blocks deal with assigning values to registers.

Assign statements do not allow blocks of code (unless you use functions). always blocks allow expressing of a hardware behavior in an algorithmic way.

some always blocks need sensitivity lists, assign do not need it.

Comment: So in some ways the always block's function is a superset of assign statement. Because 1. always block can have the option to choose sensitive values  2. always block can choose between block/non-blocking expression  3. I can put a for loop inside always block.

Comment: @YangXu They just play different roles in the design. Their capabilities reflect the roles they play. You cannot interchange them in `verilog`. In `system verilog` there are some intersections.

Answer (score 2):

A continuous assignment is just a simpler way of expressing the same thing as what you can do with an `always` block. The `assign` statement only lets you write to one signal at a time with one equation. You cannot use procedural code like `for` loops unless you wrapped it in a function.

Comment: Yes. The for loop can only run inside a block, like initial or always.

Answer (score -1):

For most purposes, an `always_comb` and `assign` will behave in similar ways though `always_comb` will likely be easier to read due to the lack of bit wise operators and ternary expressions in place of if statements.

One key difference outside of just how code looks is when it relates to setting `net` variables(variables that can be written to by multiple drivers). Here `always_comb` can NOT work while `assign` will.

Comment: If you want to explain how something like `always_comb` can be "easier to read" you should provide examples. Your reference to "bit wise operators and ternary expressions" may seem to make sense to you, but the question's nature implies the OP is not deeply savvy in the language. Your vague, oblique reference to the fact that expressions are required in `assign` but not always in `always_comb` is effectively opaque for the OP based on what seems to be their level of knowledge.